# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: crypto

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I was trying to connect firebase with React-Native project.Config file for firebase is

**firebase.js**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const config = {
    apiKey: "A***********************0",
    authDomain: "gu***********************m",
    databaseURL: "ht*******************m",
    projectId: "g*****2",
    storageBucket: "g********om",
    messagingSenderId: "########",
    appId: "####################",
    measurementId: "****************"

};


firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

**Home.js**

```
import { db } from '../config/firebase';


export default function Home() {

    var temp = {
        fruit: "apple",
        name: "banana"
    };
    db.collection('books').add(temp);
    console.log("after adding to db");
    var db1 = db.collection('books').get(temp);
    console.log("hello dude");
    console.log(db1);
    console.log("bye dude");

}
```

After I burn the app in android, it shows red screen with error:

```
ReferenceError Can't find variable: crypto

This error is located at:
    in Home (at App.js:7)
    in gullak (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

I am not able to add into firestore database. Is there something I am missing here? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your variable crypto defined?

Comment: I have not defined any variable named crypto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that you're using firebase for node.js. Crypto package is part of nodejs environment but you cannot use it in react native app.

To use firebase in React Native please take a look at this package [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

Comment: Yeah!! i was using firebase for Node.js. Invertase worked for me. Thanks!!