# Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: crypto]

Tags: react-native, redux, formik

I am trying to add a post and sent the post to the redux store with the image and some text fields data in form where I use formik to validate the data but when I click the onSubmit button I am getting the cant find variable crypto

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
      title: "",
      description: "",
      category: "",
      size: "",
      price: "",
    }}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={(values) => {
      if (imageUri.length > 0) {
        dispatch(
          postAdded({
            id: nanoid(),
            image: imageUri,
            title: values.title,
            description: values.description,
            category: values.category,
            price: values.price,
          })
        );
```

I wanted to send the post to the redux store which is set up correctly everything is fine the form is validated properly but when I click the button I am getting the crypto error

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009052/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-crypto, it makes me think you're having some trouble in your setup.